# System.getProperty("path.separator") not working as expected

Tags: java, string, split

import java.lang.System;

```
public class Splitter{

 public static void main(String args[]){

  String path_separator = "Path separator is: " + System.getProperty("path.separator");

  String str = "abc:def:gha";

  System.out.println(path_separator);

  String[] temp;

  temp = str.split(path_separator);

  for(int i=0; i<temp.length; i++)
    System.out.println(temp[i]);

 }
}
```

java Splitter

Path separator is: :

abc:def:gha

When I write

```
temp = str.split(":");
```

instead

java Splitter

Path separator is: :

abc
def
gha

So how is ":" different from ":" or what am I missing?

Same thing with:

```
System.getProperty("line.separator")
```

Thanks
Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are splitting by `str.split(path_separator);` and path separator is

```
String path_separator = "Path separator is: " + System.getProperty("path.separator");
```

which is a full sentence.

Try with:

```
str.split(System.getProperty("path.separator"));
```

Answer (score 5):

You initialize `path_separator` incorrectly, so in the first run you are trying to split `str` by `"Path separator is: :"`, not by `":"`.

Correctly the code should be

```
String path_separator = System.getProperty("path.separator");

...

System.out.println("Path separator is: " + path_separator);
```

Comment: Actually is easier to use `File.pathSeparator`, less typing :-)